# is there a way to only show the guild icon if it exists rather than using an if else statement?

Tags: discord, discord.js

this code sends a message to the server owner if invited to the server, however, because i receive an error if the guild doesn't have an icon, i had to use an if else statement just to see if it did.

this takes up an unnecessary amount of space and i was wondering if there was a way to only show the icon in the footer if it exists?

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    if (guild.icon) {
        guild.owner.send({
            embed: {
                color: 1234567,
                title: 'Thank you for inviting me!',
                footer: {
                    text: 'Invited to ${guild.name}',
                    icon_url: '${guild.iconURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true })}' // if guild has icon
                },
            }
        })
    } else {
        guild.owner.send({
            embed: {
                color: 1234567,
                title: 'Thank you for inviting me!',
                footer: {
                    text: 'Invited to ${guild.name}'
                },
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tons of ways to go about it, 1. since you are repeating the code you could just make a footer object and have a single line if statement to add `icon_url` if it exists or two just use a ternary operator

I'll show ternary / `?`:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    //dont need the backticks
    const icon_url =  guild.icon ? guild.iconURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true }) : undefined;

    guild.owner.send({
        embed: {
            color: 1234567,
            title: 'Thank you for inviting me!',
            footer: {
                text: 'Invited to ${guild.name}',
                icon_url
            },
        }
    });
});
```

The key line is

```js
const icon_url =  guild.icon ? guild.iconURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true }) : undefined;
```

What this does is, it checks if the guild has an icon, if it does it returns that string, if not it returns undefined

Another way to do it:

```js
let icon_url = guild.icon && guild.iconURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true }) || undefined;
```